# Are there any packages that I should not be using with ifthen package

Tags: spacing, conditionals

I am new to TeX and I started adding package files to prepare my document without worrying about conflicts. I am asking this subjective question because I am not sure if I can post entire document preamble here. Any generic tips would be of big help.

I uploaded [my package definition to google docs](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1XzdD5jqWOKw6tVOZOaJm8Nhe0NgV6vFKP4Ww9ubATg4/edit?hl=en&authkey=CIjl_d0H).

I am getting extra white space with `\ifthenelse` which I highlighted with a circle in the attached image. I tried using just the ifthen package and commands and it works just fine.

```
\documentclass[fleqn,12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mypackage}
\begin{document}
\Vibhakti{11} \& \Vibhakti{52} \& \Vibhakti{73}
\end{document}
```

(This should be compiled with `xelatex`.)

[image: example]

I am not sure if I am using any package that I should not be...

Comment: There isn't any attached picture.

Comment: @Caramdir: Now there is `:-)`

Comment: I am not sure why the image is not attached. I tried editing the image as well.

Comment: You had the number `[1]` inside the code block, so the image didn't appear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The lines

```
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{11}}{\underline{\textcolor{blue}{प्रथमा एकवचनम्}} }{}
                                                                    ^   ^
```

produce two white spaces at the marked positions. Note that the newline character introduces one space for each line. So you should remove the first whitespace and add a comment character (`%`) immediately after the last closing brace of each line. This will remove the white space introduced by the newline characters.

In short, you should replace the whole command definition by

```
\newcommand{\Vibhakti}[1]%
{%
%\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{1}}{}{}%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{11}}{\underline{\textcolor{blue}{प्रथमा एकवचनम्}}}{}%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{12}}{\underline{\textcolor{blue}{प्रथमा द्विवचनम्}}}{}%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{13}}{\underline{\textcolor{blue}{प्रथम बहुवचनम्}}}{}%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{21}}{\underline{\textcolor{blue}{द्वितीया एकवचनम्}}}{}%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{22}}{\underline{\textcolor{blue}{द्वितीया द्विवचनम्}}}{}%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{23}}{\underline{\textcolor{blue}{द्वितीया बहुवचनम्}}}{}%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{31}}{\underline{\textcolor{blue}{तृतीया एकवचनम्}}}{}%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{32}}{\underline{\textcolor{blue}{तृतीया द्विवचनम्}}}{}%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{33}}{\underline{\textcolor{blue}{तृतीया बहुचनम्}}}{}%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{41}}{\underline{\textcolor{blue}{चतुर्थी एकवचनम्}}}{}%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{42}}{\underline{\textcolor{blue}{चतुर्थी द्विवचनम्}}}{}%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{43}}{\underline{\textcolor{blue}{चतुर्थी बहुचनम्}}}{}%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{51}}{\underline{\textcolor{blue}{पञ्चमी एकवचनम्}}}{}%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{52}}{\underline{\textcolor{blue}{पञ्चमी द्विवचनम्}}}{}%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{53}}{\underline{\textcolor{blue}{पञ्चमी बहुचनम्}}}{}%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{61}}{\underline{\textcolor{blue}{षष्ठी एकवचनम्}}}{}%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{62}}{\underline{\textcolor{blue}{षष्ठी द्विवचनम्}}}{}%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{63}}{\underline{\textcolor{blue}{षष्ठी बहुचनम्}}}{}%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{71}}{\underline{\textcolor{blue}{सप्तमी एकवचनम्}}}{}%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{72}}{\underline{\textcolor{blue}{सप्तमी द्विवचनम्}}}{}%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{73}}{\underline{\textcolor{blue}{सप्तमी बहुचनम्}}}{}%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{81}}{\underline{\textcolor{blue}{सम्बोधन प्रथमा एकवचनम्}}}{}%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{82}}{\underline{\textcolor{blue}{सम्बोधन प्रथमा द्विवचनम्}}}{}%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{83}}{\underline{\textcolor{blue}{सम्बोधन प्रथमा बहुचनम्}}}{}%
}
```

Comment: you guys are awesome, adding the % sign at the end of each statement did the  trick.